# "Cleaned of other's sight"

Tags: phrases

What does the phrase in bold below in the sentence mean?

> One should not eat food which is **cleaned of other's sight**.

Explain the meaning and origin if possible.

EDIT: The context is a Hindu religious work called the "Virodhi Pariharam" which discusses various obstacles to spiritual progress.  Here's the relevant passage, which discusses various forms of food that are an obstacle to spiritual progress:

> The obstacles in this head are: food eaten in the houses of materialistic family; food eaten in houses of ordinary people related by natural kinships; the god's prasadam at special occasions given by people desirous of trivial objectives; not accepting prasadams in divyadesams of great influence; food eaten in houses of mere devotees of God; food self-cooked in srivaishnava houses; food given on an account; food offered for fame; wedding food; food for posthumous rites; food given for a price; defiled food; food given on a declaration; food given with some pride; food touched by others; food kept in vessels touched by others; food cooked by people thinking of other god or chanting other verses; food not cooked by people thinking of the God and reciting divyaprabandham; food not prepared with the objective of God and bhaagavatas but with the objective of oneself; food served from vessels not having the emblem of tirunamam; food not already offered to the God; food offered by ordinary people to the God; **food cleaned of others sight**; food offered only to the God and not to Sesha Seshaashana (Anantha Garuda adhi nithyasooris) and Alwars; food defiled as a category; food defiled owing to its possession; food circumstantially defiled owing to falling of worms,insects hair etc; food eaten in the row of non-bhaagavatas; food eaten after chanting bad things; food not offered with dvaya chanting; food eaten with the sense of enjoyability; food eaten without sense of its being prasadam of bhagavan; food eaten without a sense of worship of internal God; food eaten without completion of the God's worship; food not eaten as the prasadam of the food accepted by bhaagavatas; food not taken as the prasadam of a good Acharya; food eaten with a mere wrong sense as the remainder of pancha prana aahuthis; food eaten without an understanding of the power of sanctification of the seeing and touch etc of special bhaagavatas; food eaten with hesitation to mix with bhaagavatas who are sanctifiers of the row in which they are sitting (pankti pavanar); regular food in one's house and regular food in the houses of persons equal to the Acharya.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more context. Where did you find this excerpt? Can you provide a link to that source? If not, can you provide a fuller quote?

Comment: Note that [*cleansed of one's sight*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cleansed+of+his+sight%22) isn't a valid English construction, so it doesn't really "mean" anything beyond what the writer (obviously a non-native speaker) *wanted* it to mean. Which we can only guess at.

Comment: @LMS The fuller quote is given in my Hinduism.SE question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17732/36

Comment: This is not idiomatic English; it might mean "food which is cleaned *out of sight* of others", but it might equally mean "food **consumed** out of sight of others". In any case, interpreting badly translated theological texts is not something we can help with.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a translation? It seems like it may be best to see what the original text reads rather than trying to guess what the English means.

Answer (score 1):

This whole passage has poor grammar and does not read as native English.  As noted by Catija, I think this is a (poor quality) translation.

The expression "food cleaned of others sight" is not idiomatic or normal native English, and I suspect it is a mistranslated of some particular religious expression in Hindi.  There is no meaningful answer to your question about English, though there may be an answer in a spiritual or dogma context.